# woocommerce product slider plugin work for category name or id ???

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

add one ring product category in woocommerce.then I have set these category all fetaured image in home page with slider.which plugin work for product category name or id???

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for displaying product in slider.

You can also select specfic category to display product in slider

You can download free plugin form here:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-slider/